# Error on any react native http call (android only

Tags: android, ios, react-native, http, axios

I'm developing a react native app using expo.

In IOS everything works perfectly, however in Android, any http call returns an error.

In my case, I use axios, so I only have a NETWORK ERROR, without further details, but even when fetching values ​​from remoteConfig I get an error.

The API is already published.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

[Axios error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMzsf.png)

i hope the request works

Comment: Posting an image is encouraged if it helps understanding the issue better. But please don´t post code or error messages as images only. We can´t copy and test the code properly. [edit] your question and add that information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you had the related permissions in the AndroidManifest ?

In the file `android -> app -> src -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.YOUR_APP_NAME">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> //This line
   <application ... >
      ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```